# Chef node attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I would like to check if the following path to the attribute exists or not:

```
s3_bucket = node['elastic']['s3']['bucket']
```

This is the json:

```
"elastic": {
   "version": "5.4.1",
   "cluster": "cluster-dev",
   "node": "node1",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": 9201,
   "username": "elasticsearch",
   "groupname": "elasticsearch",
   "s3" : {
      "bucket": "hello"
   }
}
```

The field s3 may not exist depending on the environment, and I would like to check that before taking the attribute bucket. How I can do that?

Comment: It's just [tag:ruby] ;-)

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm using chef but i'm not used with ruby.
This is the error from chef: `chef undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With newer Chef, you can use the `node.read` method:

```
s3_bucket = node.read('elastic', 's3', 'bucket')
```

It will be `nil` if any intervening key does not exist.

Comment: Where is this method documented?

Answer (score 1):

```
s3_bucket = node['elastic']['s3']['bucket'] if node['elastic']['s3']
```